# Strange behavior of Eigen's Map

Tags: c++, eigen

When calling a function that returns a vector inside `Eigen::Map`, the map results in a wrong result. But, if the vector is first allocate and the `Eigen::Map` is applied, the expected result is achieved. Is this a bug?

[Working code](https://godbolt.org/z/56hxadvEn)

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<double> create_vector(double const a, double const b)
{
    return {a, b, a + b, a * b};
}

int main()
{
    Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Vector<double, 4>>
        eigen_vector_1(create_vector(1.0, 2.0).data());

    std::cout << eigen_vector_1 << std::endl;

    auto const vector = create_vector(1.0, 2.0);

    Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Vector<double, 4>>
        eigen_vector_2(vector.data());

    std::cout << eigen_vector_2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The vector is returned by value and `create_vector(1.0, 2.0).data()` uses its pointer so the first is undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that clang gives warning for the same: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c4xzGojj1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector is returned by value which will be destroyed at the end of the full expression and `create_vector(1.0, 2.0).data()` uses that to-be-destroyed vector's pointer so the first leads to **undefined behavior**.

This is basically a *dangling pointer* use issue.

Note that clang gives warning for the same:

```
<source>:12:15: warning: object backing the pointer will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression [-Wdangling-gsl]
```

[Warning with clang](https://godbolt.org/z/c4xzGojj1)

Comment: Which compiler flag did you use to get this warning?

Comment: @RiobaldoTatarana I used `-Wextra -pedantic`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vsqP7cdoa)

Comment: Why `gcc` does not output the same warning using the same flags? I am perplexed with that discrepancy.

Comment: @RiobaldoTatarana Yeah, I have seen this many times that one compiler warns but not the other. It is completely dependent on compiler and only an gcc implementor/expert can explain that for sure. Though, note that *"undefined behavior means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has UB. The program may just crash."* What this means is that, the standard doesn't require any kind of warning/error/crash for undefined behavior. So it is compiler's choice to produced warning.

Comment: @RiobaldoTatarana That is, the standard doesn't require any compiler to give any kind of diagnostic here.